# How to neatly check if 4 variables are the same?

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

How would someone neatly check if 4 variables are the same?

Obviously this wouldn't work:

```
if ($var1 === $var2 === $var3 === $var4)
```

But what would, without writing loads of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to go would be this:

```
if ($var1 === $var2 && $var2 === $var3 && $var3 === $var4)
```

Not a huge amount of code and it gets the job done.

Comment: `$var1 = $var2 = $var3 = ''; $var4 = false; …` — surely the last condition should be `$var3 === $var4`

Answer (score 3):

```
if(!array_diff([$var2, $var3, $var4], [$var1])){
     // All equal
}
```

Comment: @leonbloy It could be much easier if there are a lot more than 4 variables and they are put into an array in advance. It depeneds on the OPs actual code I'd say.

Comment: On the contrary, I find it easier than a long if statement to read. Clean and highly effective for lots of variables. +1

Comment: Well, in this vein, wouldn't be more readable to use `array_unique()` and check that its size is 1?

Comment: @leonbloy Indeed, that might actually be my favorite option yet. Seems like the simplest for sure. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($var1 === $var2 && $var3 === $var4 && $var1 === $var3)
```

You don't need to check if 2 and 4 are equal

Comment: "You don't need to check if 3 and 4 are equal" -> `$var3 === $var4`. Wat.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`array_unique`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) you can check if the array of unique values from the variable list is 1 (which means they are all equal):

```
if (count(array_unique([$var1, $var2, $var3, $var4])) == 1)
    // all equal
```

This comes in handy especially when comparing a long list of variables, compared to a long list of `==` checks in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ! as your master and use &&

```
if($var1===$var2 && $var1 === $var3 && $var1 === $var4)
```

But this wont let you know which of the 4 is not like the others.

Answer (score 0):

---

**In case you are dealing with many variables, I played with the below code and it works.**

---

```
$m = 'var'; //Assuming you know the variable name format $var1, $var2, $var3,...

for( $n = 1; $n <= 3; $n++) { //testing for 4 variables

     $v = "$m$n";
     $n++;
     $w = "$m$n";

     if ( $$v !== $$w ) {
       echo "false";
       break;
     }

     $n--;
}

//Breaks and echo "false" as soon as one of the variables is not equal
//Note: increase the iteration for more variable.
```